# Hide all <div> apart from one dependent on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, onchange

In my online store I have a dropdown that lists a number of products. When the dropdown changes I want to display a price.

All the prices are written in HTML within individual < div > tags with the id "ProductPrice[x]".

How do I hide all the ProductPrice[x] < div > 's but show the one that is selected using javascript?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using jQuery for tasks like this. With jQuery It becomes simple:

```
 var selectedID = ... // retrieve selected id number
 $("[id^=ProductPrice]").hide();
 $("#ProductPrice[" + selectedId + "]").show();
```

More elegant jQuery solution:

```
 var selectedID = ... // retrieve selected id number
 var selectedDiv = $("#ProductPrice[" + selectedId + "]");
 $("[id^=ProductPrice]").not(selectedDiv).hide();
 selectedDiv.show();
```